# How to print the member count of a guild with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to print the number of members in a discord guild,

```
import discord
from discord import *

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(guild_id_as_an_integer)
    
    print(guild.member_count)
    
client.run("token")
```

However it throws this error that i dont know how to solve:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kshar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kshar\Desktop\ghost bot\test.py", line 14, in on_ready
    print(guild.member_count)
  File "C:\Users\kshar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 741, in member_count
    return self._member_count
AttributeError: _member_count
```

Any advice or workarounds are much appreciated! Thankyou

Comment: What version of dpy are you using?

Comment: discord.py is 1.6.0, and python version 3.7.7 @ŁukaszKwieciński

Comment: Have you enabled the intents for your application/bot on the discord developer portal ?

Comment: yes I think so, both "presence intent" and "server members intent" are turned on in the bot section of the website, and my bot is not in over 100 servers so its not pending verification @NathanMarotte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    
    print(len(guild.members))
```

If you want to print each member too:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    

    for member in guild.members:
        print(f'{member.name}' + f'#{member.discriminator}')
        
    print(len(guild.members))
```